# How to pass the data from a row method to datable in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Hi I am using a row method which is find with datas from list of tables:

```
Row aa = new Row();
```

Inside aa it has set of datas.I need to pass this to a new datatable.

```
DataTable ss = new  Datable();
foreach(Row row in aa){
    ss.Importrows(row);
  }
```

But this is not working.
please help me out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
ss= aa.Clone();
```

Replace

```
ss.Importrows(row);
```

with

```
 ss.Rows.Add(aa.ItemArray);
```

This should work. aa should be another datatable not row.

Comment: But that is my problem. I need to pass the data's from row or a row list to datatable.

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming you have row[] array/collections then loop over collection of rows and add each row into new DataTable

```
DataTable ss = new  Datable();
foreach(DataRow dr in rowscollection)
{
   ss.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```